# Color doesn't display right in some cases after installing the color profile from Samsung

Tags: windows, display, color-profiles

I had this problem in the past when I installed Vista and don't recall what I did to fix it and now that I've upgraded to Win7 from a clean install, it's back. I've got dual Samsung SyncMaster T240 LCDs and after I install the driver/color profile everything seems ok until I open certain programs. These would be Photoshop and the Windows Image Viewer for starters. In the Windows Image Viewer white is a yellow/cream color, everything else seems ok aside from how it's got that tint to it. How would I go about fixing this? I should also mention that if anyone was looking to get one of these Touch of Color panels from Samsung (any model, we have a few at work too)…don't, the viewing angle is terrible and is even worse with two next to each other. I'll never buy this style of panel again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens in many screens actualy, I remember having seen this once ..

check this out ,

> To solve the problem and restore
>   normal colors in Windows Photo
>   Gallery, you can try one of the
>   resolutions below. All actions will be
>   done at Color Management tab, which is
>   accessible by right click on Desktop,
>   and select Personalize on the
>   contextual menu. Click on Display
>   Settings link in the Personalization
>   menu. In the Display Settings window,
>   click on Advanced Settings… button.
>   Then click on Color Management tab,
>   and finally click on Color Management…
>   button. You will need to select (tick)
>   Use my settings for this device to be
>   able to remove, change or set new
>   color profiles.

[source](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/07/11/windows-vista-photo-gallery-yellow-tint-background-problem/)

Comment: I added in the sRGB profile and set it as the default, color works as it should now. thanks