# "The monitor profile appears to be defective" warning from Photoshop Elements 6.0

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profiles

When I start the Photoshop Elements 6.0 editor I get the following warning dialogue box:

[image: The monitor profile "Samsung - Natural Color Pro 1.0 ICM" appears to be defective. Please rerun your monitor calibration software.]

I've also found that the Windows Photo Viewer shows colours completely incorrectly, and I suspect this is a related problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found via [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/41957/color-doesnt-display-right-in-some-cases-after-installing-the-color-profile-from/41959#41959), this post on [My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/07/11/windows-vista-photo-gallery-yellow-tint-background-problem/) has the solution:

> The first workaround is by removing
>   any existing ICC or WCS color profiles
>   that are been associated with all
>   display devices or monitors. Else, you
>   can also try to change the default
>   color profile for your system’s
>   monitor to sRGB IEC61966-2.1, simply
>   by clicking on Add, and then select
>   sRGB IEC61966-2.1 from the list of
>   profiles installed on system. After
>   adding, click Set as Default Profile
>   button. Exit from all dialogs and
>   reboot your computer , and the color
>   problem on Windows Photo Gallery is
>   fixed.
>
> If your system doesn’t have sRGB
>   IEC61966-2.1 profile under the ICC
>   Profiles, you can download the color
>   profile from Adobe. Unpack the zip
>   file, the right click on each of the
>   .icc files in the RGB Profiles and
>   CMYK Profiles folders (or simply just
>   the one you need to use) and click
>   “Install Profile” on context menu to
>   install the color profile to system.

In my case I just needed to remove the Samsung color profile to fix the problem.  On Windows 7 I didn't need to reboot.